# Retrieve DataTable from DataGrid table

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatable, wpfdatagrid

In my WPF application, I use a `IEnumerable<Item>` as the `ItemsSource` for my `DataGrid` table. Now that I want to print the table with the human-readable headers (instead of `Item`'s Property names), so I would love to extract/retrieve a `DataTable` object from the created `DataGrid`.

Is there anyway to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use (read from) `IEnumerable<Item>` which you have bound to `datagrid`!

Comment: Because it's not print-friendly. `IEnumerable<Item>` has PropertyName (instead of "Property name") and each item may consist of collection of some other objects. I want a more "flat" DataTable with which I can print what I want. Or in other words, I want to print out exactly what I can see from the `DataGrid`